# Как изменить цвет текста в WKWebVIew?

Tags: html, css, ios, swift, webview

У меня есть `ViewController` с `WKWebView`, я загружаю файлы `.html` и `.css` с текстом для `webView`.

Это похоже на контроллер для чтения книг в приложении Apple Books.

```
do {
  guard
  let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html")
  else {
    print("File reading error")
    return
  }

  let headerString = "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale=1.1\" />"
  let content = try String(contentsOfFile: filePath, encoding: .utf8)
  let baseUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)

  webView.loadHTMLString(headerString + content, baseURL: baseUrl)

} catch {
  print("File HTML error")
}
```

Также у меня есть 4 темы для изменения внешнего вида в `ViewController` (белая, черная, темно-синяя и желтая, как в Apple Books).

Я хочу менять цвет текста в `webView` при изменении темы.

Как это сделать? Как изменить цвет `webView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может немного извращенный способ (в HTML я вообще не силен), но можно например так :)
Пример использования в виде строчки в вашем коде:

```
do {
  guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html")
  else {
    print ("File reading error")
    return
  }
  
  let headerString = "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale=1.1\" />"
  var content =  try String(contentsOfFile: filePath, encoding: .utf8)
  let baseUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
  
  content.changeHtmlStyle(font: "Papyrus", fontSize: 5, fontColor: "red") // Эта строчка кода - пример использования. 
  
  webView.loadHTMLString(headerString+content, baseURL: baseUrl)
}
catch {
  print ("File HTML error")
}
```

Расширение для String для изменения формата HTML. Это можно добавить в любом месте приложения, вне какого-либо класса, например, под классом вашего вывода текста.

```
extension String {
  mutating func changeHtmlStyle(font: String, fontSize: Int, fontColor: String) {
    let style = "<font face='\(font)' size='\(fontSize)' color= '\(fontColor)'>%@"
    self = String(format: style, self)
  }
}
```